# Finding multi-line string in PHP file

Tags: php, arrays, string, file, multilinestring

I am working on a program in which an addon needs to modify a system file.

I have a small method in which I am finding the beginning of the string in the file like this:

```
     /**
     * @param $fileName
     * @param $str
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private function getLineWithString($fileName, $str)
    {
        $lines = file($fileName);
        foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
            if (strpos($line, $str) !== false) {
                return $line;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

I am calling that from within the method where I need to pull that string out to replace it like this:

```
//  Set our file to use
$originalFile = 'file.php';

// Find The array['key'] string
$myString = "\$array['key']";

// Process - Find it
$lineNo = $this->getLineWithString($originalFile, $myString);
```

Then `echo $lineNo;` returns `$array['key'] = array(`.

However, I need it to return the entire multi-line array/string up until the next `;` (semicolon).

How would I go about this?

Thanks

*** EDIT ***

My PHP file contents are like this:

```
<?php 
    /**
     * Comment here 
    */
     $first_array = array( 
         'key1' => 'val1', 
         'key2' => 'val2', 
         'key3' => 'val3', 
         'key4' => 'val4', 
         'key5' => 'val5' 
    );

    $second_array = array( 
        'key1' => 'val1', 
        'key2' => 'val2' 
    ); 
    ...
```

I have tried the suggestion from @Scuzzy

This is in my method now:

```
// Open Existing File And Get Contents
$myFile = file_get_contents('myFile.php');

$tokens = token_get_all($myFile);

foreach ( $tokens as $token ) {
    if (is_array($token)) {
        if( $token[0] === T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING and strpos( $token[1], "\n" ) !== false )
        {
            var_dump( $token );
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't return anything.

I need to return something like:

```
$second_array = array( 
    'key1' => 'val1', 
    'key2' => 'val2' 
);
```

As a string I can manipulate and rewrite.

Comment: Perhaps sample input and desired output would make this easier.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CA0Du9Ly I came up with a way to find the array() blocks, but not a nice way to get the var prefixing it. You could tweak it to instead capture the starting and ending line numbers.

Comment: I'm doing something similar now using `is_array($token)`...  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to parse a PHP file in PHP, depending on what you're needing to do, you might be able to use [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).

```php
require_once($filename);

// variables are now in global scope
// manipulate as necessary
$first_array['this_key'] = 'that value';

$str = '$first_array = '.var_export($first_array, TRUE).";\n\n";
$str .= '$second_array = '.var_export($second_array, TRUE).';';

// output the updated arrays back to the file
file_put_contents($filename, $str);
```

Comment: I like this, but I need to comment out the one I find or remove it completely as I am building new functionality. I was really hoping for a way to find various segments and comment or remove then I was going to append my new code to the file as needed.

Comment: ^^^ Playing with this now, I think I can make this work. Thanks @Derek.

Comment: Yep, to remove it completely, you can simply `unset()` that key in the array in question prior to the `var_export()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would be looking into http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php and in particularly `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` that have new line characters in them

`token.php`

```
$code = file_get_contents('token.code.php');

$tokens = token_get_all( $code );

foreach ( $tokens as $token ) {
  if (is_array($token)) {
    if( $token[0] === T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING and strpos( $token[1], "\n" ) !== false )
    {
      var_dump( $token );
    }
  }
}
```

`token.code.php`

```
<?php    
$bar = "single line";
$foo = "hello
multi
line
world";
$bar = 'single line';
$foo = 'hello
multi
line
world';
```

will print the multi line but not the single lines:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(318)
  [1]=>
  string(27) ""hello
multi
line
world""
  [2]=>
  int(4)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(318)
  [1]=>
  string(27) "'hello
multi
line
world'"
  [2]=>
  int(9)
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't output anything from my php file

Comment: appologies, try again but add `<?php` to the top of `token.code.php`

Comment: well, I have the following in my file...

```
<?php
 /**
  *  Comment here
  */
 $first_array = array(
  'key1' => 'val1',
  'key2' => 'val2',
  'key3' => 'val3',
  'key4' => 'val4',
  'key5' => 'val5'
 );

 $second_array = array(
  'key1' => 'val1',
                'key2' => 'val2'
 );
```
And I get nothing

Comment: Hrmm, maybe this solution isn't what you're after and I've misunderstood.

Comment: I think when he says "multi-line array/string" he means an array **definition** that spans multiple lines, not array values that span multiple lines. But a PHP parser to parse PHP is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Yes, I probably focused on the question title too strongly.

Comment: Yes. True. Sorry for not responding quicker @Scuzzy. I was editing the OP for further clarification

Comment: `token_get_all()` could be used to build a parser with, you can see that `T_ARRAY` exists when it finds `array(` but it treats the `(` as a single character without tokenisation. plus `[]` array notation would probably be hard to keep track of the nestings. try `foreach ( token_get_all( file_get_contents('token.code.php') ) as $token ) { var_dump( $token ); }` on your code, see if you can find workable patterns.

Comment: I'll need to play with that. Haven't ever used it before.  ;)